# EFCore adding default shadow properties

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb, ef-core-2.1

I'm using EFCore (With Cosmos), and for some reason it's adding a 2nd key for me, on the convention of `id`, despite having a property name `Id`, with the `KeyAttribute`.

Anyway I can stop this?

```
    public class User
    {

    public User()
    {

    }
    public User(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        Id = principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
        FirstName = principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.GivenName).Value;
        Surname = principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Surname).Value;
        Email = principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email).Value;
    }

    [Key]

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastLoginTime { get; set; }

    public Company Company { get; set; }

    public User CreatedBy { get; set; }

    //Hack to get around EF/Cosmos Enum error
    private string UserType { get; set;}

    [NotMapped]
    public UserType UserTypeEnum
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(UserType))
            {
                return Models.UserType.User;
            }
            return (UserType)Enum.Parse(typeof(UserType), UserType);
        }
        set
        {
            UserType = value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Added Shadow Property]

Comment: The second property is [alternate key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/alternate-keys), so the `Key` attribute doesn't help (works as expected - maps `Id` as PK). We need to see the missing parts of the picture - navigation properties from/to the entity in question, fluent configuration.

Comment: There is no fluent config, I'll update with the whole entity

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce (commented out the `Company` and `UserTypeEnum` properties)

Comment: *“it's adding a 2nd key for me, on the convention of `id`, despite having a property name `Id`, with the `KeyAttribute`”* – Isn’t it the other way around though? You have a key `id` and it is adding an `Id`.

Comment: Ah no, my edited code is wrong, I added `id` to fix the issue... But its still not really fixed if i do that (it works, but it's poor)

Comment: I've updated to it being Broken, and adding 'id' when it's in that state

Answer (score 0):

You can add `[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName="id")]` above your Id property

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.resource.id?view=azure-dotnet)

Comment: Nope - afraid not, it's still creating that shadow prop

Comment: Are both properties in the db?

Comment: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-dotnetcore-get-started) Example MS also used the Json convert.

Did you add those entries into cosmos using the model as above? I think I read the id is case sensitive thus the reason two entries being added and then the reason for the shadow within EF Core.

Comment: Ah so I should put "Id" as the property?

Comment: I was looking to confirm if you added the entries into cosmos with the model you showed above without [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName="id")]. I was thinking as id is case sensitive in cosmos you then sent over Id property and in turn it added another entry for Id as it didnt match id. Then every time you access cosmos its pulling back id and Id and then EF is trying to handle both.

Comment: Ahh - after checking the Cosmos release notes - looks like what I want isn't yet implemented, hence the shadow ID https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/12086 "Column property attribute"